# Python phrase labelling

Tags: python, tags, tokenize, cpu-word

Suppose I have a sentence like
sent = "safety cited many for one willful safety violation for failing to provide and ensure the use of fall protection for workers atop railcars because many workers died."

vio="safety violation for failing to provide and ensure the use of fall protection for workers atop railcars"

inc="workers died."

*resulting output should be :*

**safety_NONE cited_NONE many_NONE for_NONE one_NONE willful_NONE safety_VIO violation_VIO for_VIO failing_VIO to_VIO provide_VIO and_VIO ensure_VIO the_VIO use_VIO of_VIO fall_VIO protection_VIO for_VIO workers_VIO atop_VIO railcars_VIO because_NONE many_NONE workers_INC died_INC ._INC**

Please let me know the python script which will help me get this output.

Comment: Please make your question a [mcve]. Also check [ask] to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

```
vio = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", vio)
inc = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", inc)

sent = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sent)

labels = {"VIO": vio,
          "INC": inc}
labelled = []
for w in sent:
    label = "_NONE"
    for l, criteria in labels.items():
        if w in criteria:
            label = "_"+l
    labelled.append(w + label)
result = " ".join(labelled)
```